# SharePoint Site Collection size reduction

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

[image: Site Collection Info]I am new to SharePoint administration and looking for some guidance. I was asked to find a way to reduce the sizes (400GB+) of our site collections in our SharePoint environment and looking for ways to best handle this... Is there a list that I could possibly follow of items to check for before deleting site collections that may not be used?

Any help is much appreciated! I have googled this and kinda going down a rabbit hole but at the same time not quite understanding the jargon used.

Comment: Are the site collections 400GB+ or is that the content database?

Comment: Assuming you have more than one site collections in this content database. In that case, you might use PS Move-SPSite cmd to migrate to a new content database

Comment: The site collections (are there are multiple) are approaching or already at 400GBs. I attached a screen shot of one that is just over 400GBs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about SharePoint Site collection storage? If so there is not much you can do, clear the recycle bin and delete unnecessary files. It will be better for you to [configure a smaller SharePoint Site Quota](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/create-edit-and-delete-quota-templates) for you end users to make sure that the site will not grow to a huge size